Python's defaultInterpreterPath not respected
In VSCode 1.96.0, I have my Python interpreter path set in settings.json to ${userHome}/environments/myproject/bin/python3.  I've confirmed that this is a valid path (and that I can source ~/environments/myproject/bin/activate).  Nevertheless, programs like black and mypy are giving errors.  When I check the logs, I see
2024-12-17 10:19:19.118 [info] Workspace settings for /home/user/Projects/myproject (client side): {
    "cwd": "/home/user/Projects/myproject/python",
    "workspace": "file:///home/user/Projects/myproject",
    "args": [
        "-l 110",
        "--preview"
    ],
    "path": [
        "black"
    ],
    "interpreter": [
        "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.15/bin/python"
    ],
    "importStrategy": "useBundled",
    "showNotifications": "off"
}

Why are my workspace settings not being respected?
I've even tried manually setting the interpreter path by clicking on my environment in the lower-right.  However, after selecting ~/environments/myproject/bin/python3, there's no change.  It still shows the interpreter using used as /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.15/bin/python.
Here's my .vscode/settings.json:
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "${userHome}/environments/myproject/bin/python3",
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "tests"
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "mypy.configFile": "setup.cfg",
    "black-formatter.args": ["-l 110", "--preview"]
}


The snippet shows workspace settings being respected. If you mean why your user settings aren't being respected, it's because workspace settings override user settings.

When I open up my workspace settings in Code->Settings->Settings, I see the Python default interpreter path set to ${userHome}/environments/myproject/bin/python3.
